# How do I hide/show a UITableView programmatically in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a UITableView that I have set as hidden by default in Interface Builder. I want to set it up so that a user clicks on a button and it shows the UITableView programmatically.

Is there some method I can just call on my UITableView object in order to change its visibility?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
myTableView.hidden = NO;
```

UITableView is a subclass of UIView so inherits all UIView's properties. Look at the documentation for [-[UITableView setHidden]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden)

Answer (score 7):

You can also change the alpha on the tableview if you want to fade it in / fade it out.  For example:

Fading a view out:

```
// fade myView out
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                    myView.alpha = 0;
                 }];
```

Fading a view in:

```
// fade myView in
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                    myView.alpha = 1;
                 }];
```

Comment: This answer is worth snipping to evernote :)